# Factorizing a number into m factors to minimize the largest of them

Tags: algorithm, factors

Suppose you have a number n.
I want to decompose it as the product of its m factors.

I was thinking of an algorithm to do that.
Firstly, I am finding the largest factor(`f1`) of n below its `m th` root.
Then, replace n by `n/f1`.
Now find largest factor of n below its `(m-1)th` root

Repeat this process, I get an array of factors.

Do you think this algorithm is right? Or is there anywhere it fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm fails for this case: `n = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 = 360` and `m = 3`. Your algorithm performs the following steps:

1. Compute `360^(1/3) = 7.114...` and choose the largest factor of `360` less than this value. Hence, the factor `6` is chosen.
2. Replace `360` with `60`. The largest factor of `60` that is at most `sqrt(60) = 7.746...` is `6`.
3. Finally your algorithm chooses the last remaining factor, `10`.

So your algorithm produces the factorization `n = 6 * 6 * 10`. However, this is not optimal, since `n = 5 * 8 * 9`.

In general, your greedy algorithm might make choices that worsen the problem later on. That's what happens in this example: the first factor was chosen poorly, so that the later choices only give you suboptimal solutions.